# Sufficient conditions to specify a stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

In order to specify a stochastic process, is it sufficient to specify all the finite-dimensional distributions of the stochastic process? Can there exist two stochastic processes that agree in all the marginal distributions, but are not equal?

Comment: Sure, take two independent Brownian motions defined on the same probability space for example. But you first need to make your idea of "equal" precise.

Comment: I mean equal in distribution, but I am not sure if that is the correct term to use?

Comment: What about the reply to the first question?